# Jolt JSON Spec for Nested Object Transformation

Tags: java, json, jolt

I have a requirement to transform the Nested Object in a Json structure.
Here's the Input JSON
**Input JSON**

```json
{
  "data": {
    "PRODUCTS": {
      "ProductID": "1234-5678",
      "ModelNumber": "B550",
      "Price": "199",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "ATTRIBUTES": {
        "ProductID": "1234-5678",
        "Height": "25",
        "Width": "75"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Required Output**

```json
{
  "data": {
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": "1234-5678",
        "modelNumber": "B550",
        "unitPrice": "199",
        "quantity": "1",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "productId": "1234-5678",
            "height": "25",
            "width": "75"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**My JSON Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "PRODUCTS": "=toList"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "PRODUCTS": {
          "*": {
            "ProductID": "data.products[&1].productId",
            "ModelNumber": "data.products[&1].modelNumber",
            "Price": "data.products[&1].unitPrice",
            "Quantity": "data.products[&1].quantity",
            "ATTRIBUTES": {
              "ProductID": "data.products[&1].attributes[&1].productId",
              "Height": "data.products[&1].attributes[&1].height",
              "Width": "data.products[&1].attributes[&1].width"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {}
      }
    }
}
]
```

**Current Output**

```json
{
  "data" : {
    "products" : [ {
      "productId" : "1234-5678",
      "modelNumber" : "B550",
      "unitPrice" : "199",
      "quantity" : "1"
    } ]
  }
}
```

I want to convert the `ATTRIBUTES` nested object to a list and also the nodes inside the `ATTRIBUTES` object as per the expected output. Can someone throw some light as to how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply three steps of shift transformations;

1. To rename all keys as desired
2. To create the innermost array (`attributes`)
3. To create the outermost array (`products`)

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "ProductID": "&2.products.productID",
          "ModelNumber": "&2.products.modelNumber",
          "Price": "&2.products.unitPrice",
          "Quantity": "&2.products.quantity",
          "*": {
            "ProductID": "&3.products.attributes.productId",
            "Height": "&3.products.attributes.height",
            "Width": "&3.products.attributes.width"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "attributes": "&2.&1.&[]",
          "*": "&2.&1.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I am assuming that `&2` and `&3` are the level of the Json Keys in the input json right? What if the level of the keys are dynamic in Input Json?

Comment: @JestinoSam yes, they're are so. I think hard to make the transformation more dynamic than this while changing the keys :)